# SQL query for count AND exists

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have a DB2 table (`messages`) that tracks messages between users. There's a column for `message_id` as well as a column to track replies called `response_id` (`message.response_id` is keyed to the `message.id` that is the first message in a thread, so any messages in a given thread except the very first message will have the same `response_id`, while the first message in a thread has a `null` `message.response_id`).

There's another table (`reads`) that tracks reads on a message, and is FK'd back to the `messages` table by a column called `reads.message_id`.

Due to a bug, some message reads weren't getting recorded.

I need to find all `message`s where `message.response_id` is not null (so they're not the parent message) that DO NOT have a record in `reads` (nothing where `reads.message_id = message.id`) BUT that the parent message DOES have a valid `read` (so for a given child `message`, there IS a record matching `reads.message_id = message.response_id`).

Is this possible? Or should I just query the main message table, grab all items where `message.response_id` is not null, then do another query off of those to determine if the parent record has a `read` record?

PSEUDO-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM messages m WHERE m.response_id IS NOT NULL 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reads r WHERE m.id = r.message_id)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reads r2 WHERE m.response_id = r2.message_id)
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I think your "pseudo-SQL" looks like actual SQL that should do precisely what you want. How exactly does it fall short?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "pseudo SQL" is actually real SQL and should work.

You could use joins as an alternative:

```
select * from messages m
    join reads r2 on m.response_id = r2.message_id
    left join reads r on m.id = r.message_id
    where r.message_id is null
```

In some cases this may be more efficient.  You may need to de-duplicate the results, depending on your data.

Not that I have removed the check for whether response_id is null, because it's enforced by the first join.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a basic `not exists`:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.response_id is not null and
      not exists (select 1 from messages m2 where m2.id = m.response_id);
```

Comment: that's close, I've added some psuedo sql above to make it more clear what I am looking for